# A sufficient and necessary condition for $A \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $A \setminus (B \setminus C)$, I got $x \in A$ and $x \notin B \setminus C$.

For $(A \setminus B) \setminus C$, I have $x \in A \setminus B$, which means $x \in A$. And $x \notin C$.

By this, I don't know how to procced and find a condition to prove the equality $A \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \setminus C$.

What would I have to do after? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "$x \in A$ and $x \not \in B\setminus C$".  And what does $x \not \in B\setminus C$ mean.  Go a little further.

If $x \in A\setminus (B\setminus C)$ then $x \in A$ and either $x \not \in B$ or if $x \in B$ then $x \in C$ (as well as in $A$).  So $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$ *unless* $x \in A\cap B\cap C$.

If $x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C$.  Then $x \in A\setminus B$ and $x \not \in C$.  So $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$ and $x \not \in C$.

So whats the possible difference between:

1)$x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$ *unless* $x \in A\cap B\cap C$

2)So $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$ and $x \not \in C$

and what condition would make them both the same.

Well $2$ says that $x$ is absolutely *NOT* in $B$ and *NOT* in $C$ but 1) says $x$ *might* be in $B$ if $x \in A\cap B \cap C$, and that  $x$ might be in  $C$ if $x \in A\cap C$ but not in $B$.  To make these the same we must have $A\cap B \cap C = \emptyset$ and $(A\cap C)\setminus B = \emptyset$.  Or in other words if $A \cap C=\emptyset$.

i.e. if $A$ and $C$ are disjoint.

......

An altenative way to view this is to make a Venn Diagram:

A Venn diagram partitions the universe into eight disjoint sets based on whether elements are or are not in $A,B$ or $C$.

These eight sets are:

$A\cap B \cap C$, $A\cap B\cap C^c$, $A\cap B^c\cap C$, $A\cap B^c\cap C^c$,$A^c\cap B \cap C$, $A^c\cap B\cap C^c$, $A^c\cap B^c\cap C$ and $A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c$.

All expressions of $A$ and $B$ and $C$ will be union of some of these sets.

$A\setminus(B\setminus C) = [A\cap B\cap C] \cup [A\cap B^c\cap C]\cup [A\cap B^c \cap C^c]$.

Whereas

$(A\setminus B)\setminus C) = [A\cap B^c \cap C^c]$.

These are equal if and only if  $ [A\cap B\cap C] \cup [A\cap B^c\cap C]= [A\cap C] =\emptyset$

Comment: Okay, I understood perfectly your explanation. But the answer it's just [A∩B∩C]∪[A∩Bc∩C]=[A∩C]=∅ (sufficient and necessary)? Then I don't have to prove or demonstrate anything else?

Answer (score 0):

On the left side, you take away all element of $A$ that are in $B$ but not in $C$. On the right side you take away all elements of $A$ that are in either $B$ or $C$. In particular, on the left side any elements of $A$ that are in $C$ are also in the result, while on the right side they are removed. Thus for both sets to be equal, there cannot be any elements both in $A$ and in $C$. That is, a necessary condition is $A\cap C=\emptyset$.

Now you need to check whether that condition is also sufficient. Hint: You can ignore any elements not in $A$ (why?)